# Роутинг во Flight PHP и передача параметров

Tags: php, маршрутизация

Приветствую. Если тут есть знатоки этого микро-фреймворка, буду признателен за помощь.

Мне нужно передать параметр внутрь метода одно класса из строки url. Если верить документации, то параметр можно передать таким образом:

```
Flight::route('/test/@id', function($id) {
    echo $id;
});
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы этот параметр передался в метод класса:

```
Flight::route('/test/@id', array(
    'class',
    'method'
));
```

Собственно в этом и вопрос, как это сделать? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил таким способом:

```
Flight::route('/test/@id', ['class', 'method'], function($id){
    $a = new class();
    $a->method($id);
});
```

сразу не подумал об этом )

Answer (score 1):

Достичь желаемого результата можно так:

```
Flight::route('/test/@id', ['Test', 'testMethod']);

class Test
{
   function testMethod($id)
   {
       echo $id;
   }
}
```